# Removing multiplicative seasonality and trend from observations using Prophet?

Tags: facebook-prophet

I've fitted Prophet with logistic growth and multiplicative seasonality over time series data (daily observations spanning several years, no additional regressors; just ds, y) and have the forecast dataframe. How do I use the values from forecast to remove seasonality?

Within `forecast`, I acknowledge the `weekly` and `yearly` columns deal with seasonality on a weekly/yearly basis, and `multiplicative_terms` deals with changing magnitudes over time; but I don't know how to put this together to remove seasonality form my data.

I have the following possibly ways about attempting to remove seasonality, but believe what I'm doing is wrong.

```
#R
df$y - forecast$trend * forecast$multiplicative_terms * forecast$weekly * forecast$yearly
```

For reference, when using seasonal_decompose, I've had to use the following to get rid of seasonality; this doesn't hold for Prophet because of the additional terms.

```
#Python
df.y  - trend* decomposition.seasonal
```

Edit- After doing a bit of research, I'm currently running this which looks right, but I was wondering if anyone can confirm whether this is the correct way to remove seasonality + trend?

```
df$y - 
   (forecast$trend + 
   (forecast$trend * forecast$weekly) + 
   (forecast$trend * forecast$yearly) + 
   (forecast$trend * forecast$multiplicative_terms)
)
```